# Sequelize Association Error Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am running into an issue where I get an error message, `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined` when I try to associate a table into my query. I have a one-to-one relationship between the tables and am not sure if this is causing the error or if it is somewhere else where I am associating the two tables.

Here is my query:

```
appRoutes.route('/settings')

    .get(function(req, res, organization){
        models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
            where: { 
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            },
            include: [{
                model: models.Organization, through: { attributes: ['organizationName', 'admin', 'discoverySource']}
            }]
        }).then(function(organization, discoverySource){
            res.render('pages/app/settings.hbs',{
                user: req.user,
                organization: organization,
                discoverySource: discoverySource
            });
        })

    })
```

Here is the models.DiscoverySource model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var DiscoverySource = sequelize.define('discovery_source', {
    discoverySourceId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'discovery_source_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    discoverySource: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'discovery_source_name'
    },
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'organization_id'
    },
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            DiscoverySource.belongsTo(db.Organization, {foreignKey: 'organization_id'});
        },
    },
});
    return DiscoverySource;
}
```

Here is my models.Organization model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Organization.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'member', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
        },
    }
});
    return Organization;
}
```

Comment: For anyone facing this, the same error is yield whenever you pass anything different than an array as the `options.include[]` parameter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to rewrite your query to look like:

```
models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
    attributes: ['discoverySource'],
    where: { 
        organizationId: req.user.organizationId
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.Organization,
        attributes: ['organizationName', 'admin']
    }]
})
```

According to the Sequelize documentation:

> [options.attributes] - A list of the attributes that you want to select, or an object with include and exclude keys.
>
> [options.include[].attributes] - A list of attributes to select from the child model.
>
> [options.include[].through.where] - Filter on the join model for belongsToMany relations.
>
> [options.include[].through.attributes] - A list of attributes to select from the join model for belongsToMany relations.

So, `[options.include[].through]` can only be used in case of `Belongs-To-Many` association rather than `Belong-To` used by you for `DiscoverySource` and `Organization` models.

Answer (score 6):

In my case removing

```
through: { attributes: [] }
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me, I still don't understand why though

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks man
P.S: Sequelize lacks documentation, lots of documentation

Comment: If you are using an association where the foreign key is a column on the table itself (one-to-one, or one-to-many, although not always the case), then you do not require a `through` table (by default).

`through: { attributes: [] }` defines what attributes you want to include from the through table (Such as on a many to many relationship), and as such, will throw an error when being specified on a query/association without a through table.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. My Sequelize version `5.22.3`.
If you are using the same version then please make the following change to your query:

```
models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
    attributes: ['discoverySource'],
    where: { 
        organizationId: req.user.organizationId
    },
    include: {
        model: models.Organization,
        //rest of the code, if any
    }
})
```

include doesn't need to be an array any longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify the columns you need in include, modify your code to look like this:

```
models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
            where: { 
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            },
            include: [{
                model: models.Organization, 
                attributes: ['organizationName', 'admin', 'discoverySource']
            }]
```

So, you won't need to use the "through" keyword anymore.