# SequelizeJS Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am running into an issue where I am trying to associate two models that have a one-to-many relationship. For some reason this query is throwing an error despite referencing the relationship.

Here is my error message:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined
    at generateJoinQueries (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1181:43)
```

This is the route:

```
appRoutes.route('/settings')

    .get(function(req, res, organization){
        models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
            where: { 
                organizationId: req.user.organizationId
            },
            include: [{
                model: models.Organization, through: { attributes: ['organizationName', 'admin', 'discoverySource']}
            }]
        }).then(function(organization, discoverySource){
            res.render('pages/app/settings.hbs',{
                organization: organization,
                discoverySource: discoverySource
            });
        })

    });
```

DiscoverySource:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var DiscoverySource = sequelize.define('discovery_source', {
    discoverySourceId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'discovery_source_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    discoverySource: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'discovery_source_name'
    },
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'organization_id'
    },
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            DiscoverySource.belongsTo(db.Organization, {foreignKey: 'organization_id'});
        },
    },
});
    return DiscoverySource;
}
```

Organization:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Organization.hasMany(db.DiscoverySource, {foreignKey: 'organization_id'});
        },
    }
});
    return Organization;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize Association Error Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974514/sequelize-association-error-cannot-read-property-gettablename-of-undefined)

Answer (score 4):

It seems, that's a duplicate of [Sequelize Association Error Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974514/sequelize-association-error-cannot-read-property-gettablename-of-undefined/).

However, you need to rewrite your query to look like:

```
models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
    attributes: ['discoverySource'],
    where: { 
        organizationId: req.user.organizationId
    },
    include: [{
        model: models.Organization,
        attributes: ['organizationName', 'admin']
    }]
})
```

According to the Sequelize documentation:

> [options.attributes] - A list of the attributes that you want to select, or an object with include and exclude keys.
>
> [options.include[].attributes] - A list of attributes to select from the child model.
>
> [options.include[].through.where] - Filter on the join model for belongsToMany relations.
>
> [options.include[].through.attributes] - A list of attributes to select from the join model for belongsToMany relations.

So, `[options.include[].through]` can only be used in case of `Belongs-To-Many` association rather than `Belong-To` used by you for `DiscoverySource` and `Organization` models.