# Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a join between 2 table and make a where clause with fields from both tables, but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined
```

This are my models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var AutomatedCampaign = sequelize.define("AutomatedCampaign", {
    id:  { 
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
          autoIncrement: true, 
          primaryKey: true
        },
    campaign_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    campaign_label: DataTypes.STRING,
    medium: DataTypes.STRING,
    visible: DataTypes.INTEGER,


  }, {
    tableName: 'automated_campaigns',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: true,
  }

  );

  return AutomatedCampaign;
};



module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var AutomatedCampaignConfig = sequelize.define("AutomatedCampaignConfig", {
    id:  { 
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
          autoIncrement: true, 
          primaryKey: true
        },

    environment_hash: DataTypes.STRING,
    campaign_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    event_trigger_1: DataTypes.STRING,
    time_trigger_after_event_1: DataTypes.STRING,
    event_constraint_1: DataTypes.STRING,
    event_value_1: DataTypes.STRING,
    event_timestamp_1: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    is_deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    is_active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    html_content: DataTypes.TEXT,
    has_product_feed: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    subject_line: DataTypes.STRING,


  }, {
    tableName: 'automated_campaign_configs',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: true,
    classMethods: {
            associate : function(models) {
                AutomatedCampaignConfig.belongsTo(models.AutomatedCampaign, {foreignKey: 'campaign_id'})
            },
    },
  }

  );

  return AutomatedCampaignConfig;
};
```

And this is my query:

```
var AutomatedCampaign  = require('../models/index').AutomatedCampaign;
var AutomatedCampaignConfig = require('../models/index').AutomatedCampaignConfig;


    var values = { 

                    include: [{ 
                        model: AutomatedCampaign,
                        through: { where: { visible: 1, environment_hash: environment_hash } }
                    }]

                };

    AutomatedCampaignConfig
        .findAll(values)
        .then(function(automated_campaigns) {

            console.log('automated campaigns');
            console.log(automated_campaigns);


        });
```

Comment: Maybe helpful, I see this in the right pane: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974514/sequelize-association-error-cannot-read-property-gettablename-of-undefined?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize Association Error Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974514/sequelize-association-error-cannot-read-property-gettablename-of-undefined)

Comment: Did you figure out a resolution to this?